# Recreating complicated formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a formula that is making my file very heavy so I am trying to code it into a macro to run and only save the final values. I will need to re-run the macro daily as the values are constantly changing.

Here is my formula:

=IF($J2="P",IF(SUMIFS($D$1:D2,$I$1:I2,I2)<=SUMIFS('On Hand'!C:C,'On Hand'!B:B,I2),IF(SUMIFS('On Hand'!C:C,'On Hand'!B:B,I2)-SUMIFS($D$1:D2,$I$1:I2,I2)<=0,"Shortage",""),"Shortage"),"")

and here is what I have coded so far but it keeps throwing me an error:

```
Dim J As Integer
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer

Set ws1 = Worksheets("Jobs")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("On hand")

J = 2

Do While Range(J & "2") <> ""

    If Cells(J, 10) <> "P" Then
    Cells(J, 19) = ""
    
    Else
    If Range("I" & (J - 1) & ":I" & J) = Range("I" & J) Then
    
    a = Range("D" & (J - 1)) + Range(":D" & J)
    
    If ws2.Range("B:B") = ws1.Range("I" & J) Then
    b = ws2.Application.Sum(Range("C:C"))
    
    If a <= b Then
    If b = a <= 0 Then Range("S" & J) = "Shortage"
    Else
    Range("S" & J) = ""
    
    J = J + 1
    
Loop
```

Comment: "throwing me an error" does not say too much... What error, on what line? `ws2.Range("B:B") = ws1.Range("I" & J)` cannot be done in VBA...

Comment: `Range(J & "2")` would be equivalent to `Range("22")`. That's not a valid range reference.

Comment: Please explain what the formula is supposed to do. Don't make us guess, it's a waste of our time.

Comment: The formula is being used to calculate the consumption of purchased parts vs what we have on hand and give us a heads up by when we will run out. It checks if the part is purchase "P" and if it is, it sums the quantities (column D) for all the rows where the part number (column I)  is the same until it reaches the next part number and the sum starts back again. it then checks on the 'On hand" sheet for that same part number in column B for the total quantity on hand (column c) and then subtracts the sum of the required. when this hits 0 or negative I need the cell to show "shortage".